# Mail.app rule works only partially

Tags: macos, mail.app, email, mail-rules

I have this Mail rule:

[image]

The Move Message works great and all messages that fits the rules has been moved to the selected folder.

The issue here, is the Mark as Read part of the rule does not work.

If I alter the order (Mark as Read first and then Move Message) the Mark as Read not works.

Don't know if matters, but **the rule applys to an exchange account**.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: It's working as expected here, on Yosemite - but one thing I always do to prevent any other rule from possibly interfering, is add 'Stop Evaluating rules' to the bottom of every rule I specifically don't want to be processed by any following rule.

Comment: @Tetsujin I added Stop Evaluating rules, but no differences. Still not work.

Comment: I can only think to perhaps promote/demote the rule in the list, see if a different placing makes any difference, or deactivate all other rules to test.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. After being moved to another folder the message is marked as Unread for some reasons. And I don't have any server rules that might do that (I don't have any server rules as a matter of fact).

I'm 99% sure, that you experience such issue with an **Exchange** account, because mine are Exchange-related as well. I tested the same rule with non-Exchange account and everything works as it should, all the actions apply correctly.

You can hardly call this an answer. But at least that's an explanation of such behavior. I wanted to write it as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions.  Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you’ll be able to add [comments](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and ask follow-up questions.  To gain reputation, [answer questions that are clear and concise](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - From Review -

Comment: @fbara thanks for the viable information :) next time I will hold the solution I have till the moment I get enough reputation. And yet my answer is still more an answer, than a comment.